# Why am I getting error whenever i want to create a new laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting an error whenever I do laravel new blog

`In RequestException.php line 113:`

```
Server error: `GET http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip` resulted in a `52  
  2 Origin Connection Time-out` response:                                      
  <html>                                                                       
  <head><title>522 Origin Connection Time-out</title></head>                   
  <body bgcolor="white">                                                       
  <center><h1>522 Origin Conne (truncated...)
```

I can't figure out why. Can someone please help?

Comment: The error is very clear; the server timed out. Stack Overflow is not the place to come when a website goes down.

Comment: I think it is duplicated with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64686037/why-do-i-get-a-laravel-error-while-creating-a-new-project Update laravel with `composer global require "laravel/installer:^4.0"`
Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

To work with latest Laravel you have to update the version.

follow the step to solve the issue:

```
composer global remove laravel/installer
composer global require laravel/installer

laravel new example-app
```