# Client error: `GET http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip` resulted in a `404 Not Found`

Tags: php, laravel

I'm just starting to want to learn laravel but when I want to install laravel installer as global composer I get an error like this.

In RequestException.php line 113:

Client error: `GET http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:

```
  <html>
  <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
  <body>
  <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
  <hr><center>nginx</c (truncated...)
```

Comment: You're most likely following an old tutorial. If you want to install it using composer, check [this guide](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#installation-via-composer).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a laravel error while creating a new project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64686037/why-do-i-get-a-laravel-error-while-creating-a-new-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should check that your Composer install is up to date with `composer update` - this is just general good practice.

Also make sure you're following an up-to-date guide. The latest guide at the time of this post is here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#installation-via-composer

Further up in the article are OS specific guides if you can't get Composer to work.

Edit: Here's a troubleshooting guide for Composer too: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md