# Can't update laravel installler 1.5.0 from ubuntu 20.04

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, installation

After I installed [Laravel 9](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x#getting-started-on-linux) in Ubuntu 20.04 (php 7.4 and composer 2.3.10) I run

```
laravel new proyect1
```

but it does not work. I got this error: In RequestException.php line 113: Server error: `GET http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip` resulted in a `522`  response

When I searched for the error message, I found this question in StackOverflow:

[Why do I get a laravel error while creating a new project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64686037/why-do-i-get-a-laravel-error-while-creating-a-new-project)

But the solutions suggested on it did not work for me. Basically, it recommends removing the laravel installer and requiring it again,  Basically, it recommends removing the laravel installer and requiring it again, but even when I followed the solution that was suggested, laravel/installer version 1.5.0 appears when I ask for the laravel installer version instead of laravel/installer 4.2.13 version

Comment: If you have PHP 7.4 you should be able to update the Laravel installer to a newer version - `composer global update laravel/installer`. You can also check your global `composer.json` file to check if it took effect `cat ~/.composer/composer.json`.

Comment: If that doesn't work I recommend following the [Updating the Laravel Installer](https://laravel-news.com/updating-the-laravel-installer) from Laravel News.

Comment: thank you @KimHallberg but I did what you suggest before I published this problem. I edited the expanation in order to be more especific. I really apreciate if someone knows how to solve this.